# how to append a file to the second column of another tsv file

Tags: awk, command

I have a file first.txt that looks like this :

```
45
56
74
62
```

I want to append this file to second.tsv that looks like this(there are 17 columns) :

```
2   a   ...
3   b   ...
5   c   ...
6   d   ...
```

The desired output is :

```
2   45   a   ...
3   56   b   ...
5   74   c   ...
6   62   d   ...
```

How can I append to the second column?
I've tried

```
awk -F, '{getline f1 <"first.txt" ;print $1,f1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17}'  second.tsv
```

but did not work. This added the columns of first.txt to the last column of second.tsv, and it was not tab separated.
Thank you.

Comment: Write some code to try to solve the problem and then include that code in your question if you get stuck and need help. See [ask].

Comment: @Ed Morton Thank you for your suggestion. I'd added some codes I'd tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works if you remove the `-F,` bit.  This tells awk that the file is comma-separated, which it is not.

Another option would be to go for a piped version with `paste`, e.g.:

```
paste first.tsv second.tsv | awk '{ t=$2; $2=$1; $1=t } 1' OFS='\t'
```

Output:

```
2   45  a   ...
3   56  b   ...
5   74  c   ...
6   62  d   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next} {$1=$1 OFS a[FNR]} 1' file1 file2
2 45 a ...
3 56 b ...
5 74 c ...
6 62 d ...
```

If your files are tab-separated add `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` at the front.